# Chrome dev tool error- Status in network tab is CORS ERROR while fetching image from Alibaba OSS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, alibaba-cloud-oss

```
fetch(url).then((response) => {
        return response.blob();
    }).then(blob => {
        return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
```

My `url` in `fetch()` actually a image url of different domain which is OSS_URL of Alibaba Cloud.
How can i have full access over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should config CORS on your Alibaba cloud.
check their docs like [here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31903.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're fetching in this snippet `fetch(url)` Is blocking your request because that `url` isn't accepting requests for its resources unless its from a trusted source.

You need to Add CORS policy's to your server which will tell the server the URL you're requesting from is safe.

`Your url (localhost) -> request to server -> Server declines (localhost)`

This is creating the CORS error because the Server your requesting from doesn't allow resource sharing between untrusted sites.